# What expression can be used to say that you are willing to work abroad?

Tags: translation

I am translating my resume from French to English and I would like to say that I would agree to (not want to but accept to, it is not required) work abroad. In French I just wrote "Mobilité internationale". Would "international mobility" sound natural to English or American people?
Thanks.

Edit : I'd like a one or two words expression to add to a keywords list

Comment: *...overseas job placement*.

Comment: What's wrong with "Willing to work abroad"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Nothing's wrong, I just looked for something shorter because I planned to put it in a list of keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is **French Passport. Willing to travel/relocate.** I realize that as a French-speaker you might equally well have a Canadian passport or a Haitian passport, or something else entirely, but the basic principle is the same.

Having been in the position of recruiting internationally, one of the first questions in my mind was “can this person work for me without legal or immigration issues?” soon followed by “can they do the job?”, and “can they handle living here?”  Dual citizenship can be a plus. If you have previously qualified for a skills-based visa, or have an internationally-recognized qualification, this may be worth mentioning. Same thing with education, language skills, and other things to convince your prospective employer that you’re not going to be a burden.

Practically speaking, “international mobility” (definitely not a common English expression) is about the *other* attributes you possess, which determine whether you are mobile in the employment sense.  It obviously helps if you can express yourself idiomatically on a resume in your target language, and in addition to the suggestions you’ll see here, I’d suggest a quick glance at LinkedIn to see how your English-speaking counterparts describe themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I would accept [**international**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/international) work.

> extending across or transcending national boundaries